# Problema con la carga de datos en un datagrid en c# usando Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, datagridview

actualmente estoy realizando una aplicación la cual se encarga de tomar un archivo de texto y cargarlo en un datagrid.

En mi codigo lo que hago es tomar este archivo, leer cada linea y de cada linea voy sacando los datos que necesito con **.SubString()**, estos datos se guardan en listas y después con un boton llamo a estas listas y cargo los datos al datagrid. Esto se hace bien pero me di cuenta de un detalle, cuando yo limpio la grilla y cargo de nuevo el archivo en la primera columna que tengo agrega un dato que se va auto incrementando desde 1 hasta la cantidad de lineas que tenga mi archivo.

Lo primero que pensé fue que yo en el código estaba poniendo que en esta primera fila vaya un dato numérico que se incrementara, efectivamente lo tenía pero lo borré, guardé los cambios y ejecuté pero me sigue saliendo.

Voy a poner el código para ver si alguien puede ver algo que se me esté pasando por alto:

Para buscar el archivo tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void bt_BuscarArchivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Title = "Buscar Archivo";
    string usuario = Environment.UserName; //obtengo el usuario que inicia sesión en el equipo

    open.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\" + usuario + @"\Downloads";

    open.Filter = "Archivos Soportados (*.txt;*.data; *.dat)|*.txt;*.dat;*.data";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && open.ToString() != " ")
    {
        txt_RutaArchivo.Text = open.FileName; //o mostramos en el textline
        ruta = open.FileName; //se guarda en variable para ser usado después

        extension = Path.GetExtension(ruta);
        NombreArchivo = Datos.ObtenerNombreArchivo(ruta);
        fname = NombreArchivo;
    }

    ContArchivo = Datos.AsignarLargoArchivo(ruta);
    txt_larchivo.Text = ContArchivo.ToString();

}
```

Después de tomar el archivo lo analizo: las lineas pueden tener dos largos, 72 caracteres o 75, esto lo controlo con un **if else**, en esta parte lo único que hago es tomar de las lineas la parte que necesito y guardarlas en listas:

```
private void bt_AnalizarArchivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        cadena = new string[ContArchivo];
        salida = new string[ContArchivo];
        nDocumento = new string[ContArchivo];
        lDocumento = new string[ContArchivo];
        fDocumento = new string[ContArchivo];
        nContrato = new string[ContArchivo];
        tDocEntrada = new string[ContArchivo];
        aDocEntrada = new string[ContArchivo];
        nEntrada = new string[ContArchivo];
        iDocEntrada = new string[ContArchivo];
        mCIF = new string[ContArchivo];
        vCIF = new string[ContArchivo];
        mVenta = new string[ContArchivo];
        vVenta = new string[ContArchivo];
        PosicionArray = new string[ContArchivo];
        //local = new string[ContArchivo]; pendiente porque tienen que dar el si

        //uso de libreria FileStream
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(ruta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            //aca se guarda la linea, lo que tenga
            string line;
            i = 0;
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Length == 72)
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    cadena[i] = line;
                    salida[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida2[1]));
                    nDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pndocumento2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pndocumento2[1]));
                    lDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pldocumento2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pldocumento2[1]));
                    fDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pfdocumento2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pfdocumento2[1]));
                    nContrato[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pncontrato2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pncontrato2[1]));
                    tDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Ptdocentrada2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Ptdocentrada2[1]));
                    aDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Padocentrada2[0]), int.Parse(Datos.Padocentrada2[1]));
                    nEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pnentrada2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pnentrada2[1]));
                    iDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pidocentrada2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pidocentrada2[1]));
                    mCIF[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmcif2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmcif2[1]));
                    vCIF[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvcif2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvcif2[1]));
                    mVenta[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmventa2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmventa2[1]));
                    vVenta[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvventa2[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvventa2[1]));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else //75
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    cadena[i] = line;
                    salida[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida[1]));
                    nDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pndocumento[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pndocumento[1]));
                    lDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pldocumento[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pldocumento[1]));
                    fDocumento[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pfdocumento[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pfdocumento[1]));
                    nContrato[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pncontrato[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pncontrato[1]));
                    tDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Ptdocentrada[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Ptdocentrada[1]));
                    aDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Padocentrada[0]), int.Parse(Datos.Padocentrada[1]));
                    nEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pnentrada[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pnentrada[1]));
                    iDocEntrada[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pidocentrada[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pidocentrada[1]));
                    mCIF[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmcif[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmcif[1]));
                    vCIF[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvcif[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvcif[1]));
                    mVenta[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmventa[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pmventa[1]));
                    vVenta[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvventa[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Pvventa[1]));


                    i++;
                }
            }


        }

        MessageBox.Show("El análisis del archivo " + extension + " está listo", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);



    if (bandera == 0)
    {
        bandera = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        bandera = 1;
    }

}
```

Después de hacer esto, con otro botón, muestro los datos, usando un while voy agregando a mi dataGridView1:

```
private void bt_MostrarDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;

    //agregamos los datos al datagriw y vemos si tienen errores
    while (i <= ContArchivo - 1)
    {
        //se ingresan los datos
        //saco los datos de las variables y los voy agregando fila por fila
        //  !! acá debería validar

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(salida[i], nDocumento[i], lDocumento[i], fDocumento[i], 
                                nContrato[i], tDocEntrada[i], aDocEntrada[i], nEntrada[i], 
                                iDocEntrada[i], mCIF[i], vCIF[i], mVenta[i], vVenta[i]
            );

        //validación de los campos para que los pinte
        Datos.ValidarSalida(dataGridView1, i, salida[i]);
        Datos.ValidarNumeroDocumento(dataGridView1, i, nDocumento[i]);
        Datos.ValidarNumeroLineas(dataGridView1, i, lDocumento[i]);
        Datos.ValidarFechaDocumento(dataGridView1, i, fDocumento[i]);
        //Datos.ValidarNumeroContrato(dataGridView1, i, nContrato[i]);  todavía no valido, 
        Datos.ValidarDocumentoEntrada(dataGridView1, i, tDocEntrada[i]);
        Datos.ValidarAñoEntrada(dataGridView1, i, aDocEntrada[i]);
        Datos.ValidarNumeroDocumentoEntrada(dataGridView1, i, nEntrada[i]);
        Datos.ValidarItemDocEntrada(dataGridView1, i, iDocEntrada[i]);
        Datos.ValidarMonedaCIF(dataGridView1, i, mCIF[i]);
        //Datos.ValidarValorCIF(dataGridView1, i, vCIF[i]);
        Datos.ValidarMonedaVenta(dataGridView1, i, mVenta[i]);
        //Datos.ValidarValorVenta(dataGridView1, i, vVenta[i]);

        i++;
    }
    //
    //bandera = 1;
    mostrarDatos = 1;

    //si hay errores
    if (HayErrores == 1)
    {
        HayErrores = 0;
        GuardarErrores.LosErrores();
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha generado un documento de texto con la información de las lineas que tienen errores en:" + Environment.NewLine + "C:/Archivo_Rentas", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        // abro la carpeta donde está el archivo con los errores
        string path = "C:/Archivo_Rentas";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
    }

}
```

Y ya para limpiar la grilla uso:

```
private void bt_LimparDatagridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

He probado las siguietes formas, cargar el archivo de 75 (carga bien), limpiar, cargar de nuevo y aparece esta fila.

Cargar archivo, no limpiar, cargar de nuevo y si voy al final de la grilla veo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cierro el programa y cargo el archivo que tiene largo de 72 es lo mismo, la primera vez carga bien pero limpiando y cargando el archivo de nuevo aparece esta linea.

¿Puede ser el cómo limpio la grilla?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Has intentado debug con breakpoint?

Comment: Si pero ya lo solucioné. Me demoré un poco pero dentro de mi archivo estaba llamando a una función en donde estaba agregando una fila de más.